# No Module Find Katna while I install it using pip3 and also with pip

Tags: python-3.x

I installed Katna but still it show ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'katna'. What is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
pip install katana
```

I think you have a typing error while installing Katana

Comment: did you solve the problem, kindly vote up if it was helpful